# Possible to use usb headset for game audio?

Tags: ps3, audio-hardware

I know that this is an age old question, but can you use a usb headset on a PS3 for both chat and game audio? I know that the firmware didn't use to support it, but now that Sony has their ***USB*** stereo headset, I thought for sure it would be possible. I don't know if it still isn't, or I'm just not searching google good enough.

Does anyone have some concrete evidence that it is **NOT** possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any evidence to show that it is NOT possible, I can however link you to an [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_4682970_usb-headset-work-ps.html) of how you CAN. It seems to be simple enough:

- Plug in the headset.
- Go to the `Audio Device Settings` on the PS3 and set the headset as both `Input Device` and `Output Device`.

Comment: IIRC "Audio output device" will only output chat, not game audio, but I may need to check this

Comment: @JohnoBoy Please do, I don't have the means to (don't own a PS3 nor USB headset). The internet doesn't have any conclusive evidence for as far as I can find...

Comment: I'll check once I have access to my PS3

Comment: I have checked this already. It only outputs chat like @JohnoBoy says.